# How can I delete a table from metadata BEFORE sharing the metadata to a repository?

Tags: ibm-information-server

I have imported metadata from a database that has over 15,000 tables. I would like to delete the extra tables before I share the metadata to the repository. So far, all my research has told me I can only do this **after** I've shared the metadata. Is there any way to do this before I share it even once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to delete the extra tables by going to IMAM and clicking on "Import" -> the import area I wanted to work on -> "Staged Imports" -> "Reimport..." -> the magnifying glass icon next to the text area for "Assets to import" -> selecting and deselecting tables as required.